# RegEx And Matching With Suffix

Tags: php, regex

I am on my last part of this customer project, and having one last issue from testing and debugging. The problem lies with matching based on the base word, for the highlighting.

For example, the search word is "contract", the text being search can contain "contracts, contracting, contracted", which should all match, and highlight. However, I also need the flip-side, the search word could be "contracted", and the text being searched, is "contract".

The text to search is coming from a DB, and my SQL is bringing in the proper records, I also have it narrowed down to a couple of sentences for a preview. I tried messing around with some ideas, such as match by word length such as "/[contract]{8,}/", "contracts", which works, for the first part, of the example.

here is the relevent code sample:

```
    //Get Preview Of Found Records
    $RecordFound = $Title;
    $SearchInput = $TestText;
$RegExPattern = preg_quote($SearchInput, '/');
$RegExPattern = "/^.*$RegExPattern.*\n.*\n.*\$/m";

if(preg_match_all($RegExPattern, $RecordFound, $matches)){
    echo $PostID." - Area = ".$AreaPK." Type = ".$TypePK;
    echo "<br/>";
    //Send Preview For Highlighting
    echo highlight(implode("\n", $matches[0]), $SearchInput);
    echo "<br/>";
}
  function highlight($text, $words) {
  preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
if(!$m)
    return $text;
$re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';

return preg_replace($re, '<SPAN style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffff00"><b>$0</b></SPAN>', $text);
}
```

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: `[contract]{8,}` is 8 or more `c`, `o`, `n`, `t`, r`, or `a` characters. Try `contract.*`... in SQL you could use like `like 'contract%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to find the full word (everything until space\new line)

```
(contract[^\s,.]*)
```

View https://regex101.com/r/SbhZGo/2 for examples

In your case, you could just replace contract with any words ie:

```
(ball[^\s,.]*)
```

will find ball, balls, balloon etc

Comment: *"Will there ever be...?"*: answers are not intended to ask questions. Post a comment instead.

Comment: There is an answer already and it answers what he is asking for just fine. I am however asking if he need the answer to be improved for a case he didn't mention. @trincot

Comment: And that, @Maslo, is what comments are for.

Comment: Maslo, it is possible, and thought about that. However I am in the mood today, that a user should also think about what they are searching for. I am normally not in that mood, but this part of the project has me so frustrated, more so with myself, not being able to figure out RegExs. I am coming from a desktop environment, to web, and not going as well as it should. However, would i use your snippit, in the highlight func?

Comment: @Maslo, love that link you sent, it may be just the tool I have been looking for =).

Comment: @MaxThrust, I updated the answer to accommodate for dots and commas that I hadn't thought about. Updated the link with examples.